# Why do the author need to add <Async<List<Task>>> for catch in Flow in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

The following code comes from the [project](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples).

And  `_filteredTasksAsync` will return  `Flow<Async<List<Task>>>` .

I don't know why the author need to add `<Async<List<Task>>>` for `catch` in Flow in Kotlin?

You know the the `.map{}` needn't to add `.map<Async<List<Task>>> {}`

```
private val _savedFilterType =
        savedStateHandle.getStateFlow(TASKS_FILTER_SAVED_STATE_KEY, ALL_TASKS)

    private val _filterUiInfo = _savedFilterType.map { getFilterUiInfo(it) }.distinctUntilChanged()
    private val _userMessage: MutableStateFlow<Int?> = MutableStateFlow(null)
    private val _isLoading = MutableStateFlow(false)
    private val _filteredTasksAsync =
        combine(taskRepository.getTasksStream(), _savedFilterType) { tasks, type ->
            filterTasks(tasks, type)
        }
            .map { Async.Success(it) }   // .map <Async<List<Task>>> { Async.Success(it) }  isn't necessary
            .catch<Async<List<Task>>> { emit(Async.Error(R.string.loading_tasks_error)) }   //.catch { emit(Async.Error(R.string.loading_tasks_error)) }  will cause error


sealed class Async<out T> {
    object Loading : Async<Nothing>()    
    data class Error(val errorMessage: Int) : Async<Nothing>()    
    data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : Async<T>()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you omit `<…>`, you are allowing the generic type of the function to be inferred. With `map`, you can always omit it, because the type can be inferred to be whatever type you are returning from the lambda.

With the `catch` call here, it would be able to infer the type if you were emitting the same type as the known type of the flow returned from the preceding `map` operator. However, the returned type of the Flow from the `map` operator is `Async.Success`. In the `catch` operator, we are not emitting `Async.Success` so the types don’t match and therefore cannot be inferred. We need to specify the nearest common parent type which is just `Async`.

You could also move the generic type specification up to the `map` line, and then it wouldn’t be needed for the `catch` line:

```
.map<Async<List<Task>>> { Async.Success(it) }
.catch { emit(Async.Error(R.string.loading_tasks_error)) }
```

IIRC, they have recently improved the Kotlin compiler so you don’t have to specify every detail of a nested generic type if it’s not changing, so I think this would work:

```
.map<Async<_>> { Async.Success(it) }
.catch { emit(Async.Error(R.string.loading_tasks_error)) }
```

Answer (score 1):

`catch` on `Flow` is defined as: (https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/catch.html)

```
fun <T> Flow<T>.catch(action: suspend FlowCollector<T>.(cause: Throwable) -> Unit): Flow<T>
```

Therefore, if you specify  in `catch`, that would only be required if it could not be inferred, which cannot be determined solely from the context of the given code, but I am assuming that since the type of Action in `map` could be inferred, the explicit  is not required, however it would make the type of the `Flow<Async.Success<List<Action>>>`, which is not equal to `Flow<Async<List<Action>>>`, so the sole purpose here is to "downcast" the flow explicitely.

Comment: Was this generated by [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned)?